# Linux file permissions and Java problems (permission retention)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, filesystems, retain

I run servers on my Linux Server (Ubuntu) and there's a bit of a problem. It may seem simple to fix, however I don't think it is. The servers run in my username (server), however, others access certain files with different users via FTP. Because the server is running in my username, whenever a plugin creates new files, they do not have permission to edit etc.

I have tried putting the users into groups and then allowing group access to that folder (even for new files), but had no luck. Every time they need to edit the files, I need to `chmod -R 777` it.

I thought about running the servers in their usernames, however that would produce complications. Is it actually possible to make new files retain the permissions of the parent (or a top folder)? All the solutions I've found doesn't seem to work.

Comment: *DO NOT* use mode `777` on files.

Comment: @Daenyth I know there's a lot of hype about that, however, I don't see what's wrong with it (and, to be honest, that's another question, so please don't tell me I shouldn't, as I still will)

Comment: @rooftop Looking into umask now...

Answer (score 1):

Not for users but for groups. You can:

```
chmod g+s parent_dir
chgrp shared_group parent_dir
```

If you create files inside it, that files will have the group of the folder (shared_group).

Comment: I tried this, however when I upload a file, it has `adfrw (0644)` permissions. Is it possible to change some ProFTPD settings for default upload perms too?

Comment: This still doesn't work. Whenever I try to edit a file, it says permission denied, as it has 0644 permission. It seems as if the permissions are being 'inherited'. By the way, there are multiple levels of folders, so is it possible to do a recursive umask? But still, this is too much hassle to keep repeating every time this happens. I need a solution...

Comment: @Daenyth I can't even delete the files via FTP now. Just still permission denied.

Comment: Make sure you're adding the user to the group.

Comment: If you can not delete a file check your directory permissions, not the file. And check this to how to set the default permissions to newly created files: http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Umask.html